# Call a method repeatly when button is pressed

Tags: android, performance

I want to call the method `sendDate` while the button is pressed.
But unfortunately I am getting an endless loop and my app freezes.
Maybe I can try it with a handler but I am not sure.

```
controllerButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            while (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (liftStatus == LIFT_IS_UP) {
                    sendData(3);
                } else if (liftStatus == LIFT_IS_DOWN) {
                    sendData(1);
                }
            }

            if (liftStatus == LIFT_IS_UP) {
                sendData(4);
                return true;
            } else if (liftStatus == LIFT_IS_DOWN) {
                sendData(2);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

**sendData Method**

The Method is to control a lift which is via Bluetooth LE connected

```
private void sendData(int command){
        if (myBluetoothGattCharacteristic != null) {
            switch(command) {
                case 1:
                    myBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue("Lift_UP_START");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue("Lift_UP_STOP");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue("Lift_DOWN_START");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    myBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue("Lift_DOWN_STOP");
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            myGatter.writeCharacteristic(myBluetoothGattCharacteristic);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can try to use an `onClickListener` instead of an `onTouchListener`. This is the normal listener for a button click.

Comment: @Marcel50506 how would solve that my problem?

Comment: Firstly don't make time consuming actions on UI thread. Run it on separate thread. Secondly investigate the endless loop further. Even outside main thread this should not happen.

Comment: What does the method "sendData" do?

Comment: @SimonSchubert I updated my code

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong. Looking at your code, the while loop investigates the `motionEvent.getAction()`, which, if true, remains true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `while statement` because once you received the motion event with `ACTION_DOWN` event, the value of `motionEvent.getAction()` will be the same forever till the end of this function  hence you are trapped in you while loop and the value of event is never changed in your loop, hence endless loop

```
while(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ // unwanted while ,  remove this while loop , use if-else or switch ,
//like if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
// check your up and down}

        if (liftStatus == LIFT_IS_UP){
            sendData(3);
         }else if (liftStatus == LIFT_IS_DOWN ){
            sendData(1);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. I would also do it with a handler.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable mConnectionCheck = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

public void sendData(int value) {
    mHandler.post(mConnectionCheck);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can't have the while loop inside your touch listener. That doesn't allow the callback to return and freezes up your ui. Starting from the code you posted, I would use a `Handler` that keeps executing a `Runnable`:

```
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            handler.post(new MyRunnable({some_value}));
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

and in the class where you are using it:

```
private Handler handler;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private int value;

    public MyRunnable(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        sendData(value);
        <check if you need to change this.value>
        handler.post(this);
    }
}
```